# attempting to export all the pictures from disk give 500 internal error

Tags: php, export, internal-server-error, php-ziparchive

I am attempting to export all the pictures from disk but unfortunately after a long time it give 500 internal error.

There are many batches for export. Some batches export all images to zip with the help of **ZipArchive** but when images are above 1000 it gives internal error after taking many minutes. From where I can debug it?  I am confused .

```
if (file_exists($zipPath)) {
        // open archive 
        if ($zip->open($zipPath, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
            die ("Could not open archive");
        }
        // add files
        foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
            $FilePath = explode('/', $picture['image']);
            $FileName = $FilePath[count($FilePath)-1];
            $zip->addFile($picture['image'], $picture['Year'] . '/' . normalizeString($picture['State']) . '/' . normalizeString($picture['County']) . '/' . normalizeString($picture['City']) . '/' . normalizeString($picture['Parcel_ID']) . '/' . $FileName) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $FileName");
        }
        // close and save archive
        $zip->close();
    }
```

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @UweAllner please check . now i added code what i done. $pictures contains data fetch from database.

Comment: this is wrong `if (!file_exists($zipPath))`, use this `if (file_exists($zipPath))`, you run the zip code when **file does not exist**

Comment: if the file exists it can open and add the files